# In Wing IDE, how do I enable "break on exceptions" in the debugger? (exception-always-stop ())

Tags: wing-ide

This doc says there's an option for it, but how do I enable it?

`exception-always-stop ()`

http://www.wingide.com/doc/commands/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it

`Exceptions tab` -> `Options` -> `Configure` -> `Exceptions` -> `Report:` -> `Always Immediately`

I think what confused me was that instead of having a checkbox for "break on exceptions" like most IDEs, it is calling this "Report Exceptions Always Immediately" as an exception reporting mode, and it's under exception options and not debugger or breakpoint options

Comment: That exception mode reports every exception that happens, even if handled internally.  Not usually that useful, except for short periods of time.  In general the debugger should stop on exceptions unless they are handled and never printed.  There are some details on the options available in http://wingware.com/doc/debug/managing-exceptions

Comment: I don't mind it because I hit "Ignore exception location" a brajillion times and then things work well from then on :) The reason is I have a custom exception handler that handles all exceptions so Wing rightfully thinks not to break since it is 'caught'

Comment: Another idea is to instead set a breakpoint in the exception handler.  Also, you can add code like this:

    import os
    import logging
    if 'WINGDB_ACTIVE' in os.environ:
        logging.exception()

Or you can replace the call to exception() with 'raise' but that actually re-raises the exception, which you may not want.

Comment: Sorry, newlines and code blocks in comments don't seem to be working as documented but I hope you can see what I'm saying... also using logging.exception() assumes you have the default When Printed exception handling mode.